# Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module (AWS Lambda)

Tags: aws-lambda, node-modules, npm-install, sharp, claudiajs

I have Vue.js app pushed on a staging website.

When I run the app using my local backend, everything works fine. I'm able to use the sharp module to crop images, they get saved to an AWS S3 bucket and display correctly.

However, once I try to deploy the server to AWS Lambda using *claudia update*, it does not work on the live site. I think this is because the node module is being installed clean and for some reason AWS cannot find the module (even though I can download it on my local machine).

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? Thank you in advance!

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "\nSomething went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module\n\nCannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'\n\nPossible solutions:\n- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp\"\n- Install for the current runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"\n- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ",
        "Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module",
        "",
        "Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'",
        "",
        "Possible solutions:",
        "- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp\"",
        "- Install for the current runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"",
        "- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:30:9)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)",
        "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:8:1)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: ever find the solution?

Answer (score -6):

When you install sharp use:

```
npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp
```

instead of:

```
npm install sharp
```